# mouseenter/leave img to fadeIn/Out text div not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that I would like to fadeIn a caption div. The caption div should fadeIn directly over the image when the mouse enters the div and fadeOut when the mouse leaves.

Secondly, I'd like to add a click toggleClass function to select and de-select the image. When the image is selected, the caption should remain revealed/displayed. When the image is de-selected with a click, the caption should fadeOut.

Bottomline: 1) mouseenter/leave to fadeIn/out caption 2) click to toggle select class to keep the caption displayed or de-select to hide.

The FiddleJS: http://jsfiddle.net/jhyqt5/cBsqN/

HTML:

```
 <div class="caption">Into the Night</div>

<img src="https://scontent-a-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/189612_10100244250167513_7332862_n.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .img-circle{
    border-radius: 50%; height: 140px; width: 140px;
}
.caption{
    background-color: black; opacity: .7;
    text-align: center; line-height: 120px; color: white;
    position: absolute; display: none;
    border-radius: 50%; height: 140px; width: 140px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.caption').mouseenter(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.fadeOut();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add `jquery` in your fiddle. Second you can achive the hover effect with css itself you don't need jquery except for the second thing. Add a wrapper to wrap your img and overlay and just add some css rules to it.

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.caption {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .7;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
}
.wrapper:hover .caption{ /*Show it when hovered*/
     display: block;
}
.wrapper.active .caption{ /*Show it always when parent has class active*/
     display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="caption">Into the Night</div>
    <img src="https://scontent-a-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/189612_10100244250167513_7332862_n.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); //toggle the class to add or remove each click
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N2NJ8/)**

Comment: This was great! Thanks for the demo. I actually just started coding a week ago, what does it mean when say "add jquery to your fiddle"? The fiddle link I sent is actually my first attempt too, please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is malformed, try this for the fade effect

```
<div class="image">
<div class="caption">Into the Night</div>

<img src="https://scontent-a-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/189612_10100244250167513_7332862_n.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.image').mouseenter(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.fadeOut();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDWzm/1/